# Tight bound on the worst running time

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I have to find a tight bound for an algorithm.

I ended up with $3n^2 + 5$ as the worst running time of the piece of code.

Is it ok if I consider $n^2$ as the tight bound?
$$3n^2 + 5 \in \Theta(n^2)$$

My justification is the following:
$$3n^2 \le 3n^2 + 5 \le 8n^2$$

Comment: Your justification is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree that reasoning. Intuitively I would ignore any addition or multiplication of scalars from the bound.